# Logging on worker thread

Tags: ios, logging, grand-central-dispatch

Do I need to put `println` calls to main thread, when long running operation is executed on a work thread, or is it ok, doing without it?

Comment: Logging on the background thread is fine. They do not have to be on a main thread.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not call log operations on main thread, because it's not mandatory, as for UI changes